# Offline tests pass when ran in IntelliJ but fail when ran with mvn

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I have written a unit test which uses a class (let's call it A)

This class A can be found directly in one of the dependencies D1 in my pom.xml and can also be found in 2 other dependencies D2 & D3 declared in the same pom but is part of a transitive dependency of these 2 dependencies, so this is roughly what the situation looks like:

```
Project
|____
|    D1
|    |__ A (v1)
|____
|    D2
|    |__TD1
|       |__A (v1)
|____
     D3
     |__TD2
        |__A (v2)
```

Just for clarification, TD stands for transitive dependency and v1 is an older version of class A while v2 is the newest one.

Now, what's happening is that if I run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` on my project which contains classes that use methods that can only be found in the newest version (v2) of class A, it builds successfully. However, if I remove the `-DskipTests` flag and let the tests run, they fail because they couldn't resolve a method ( which should be available in v2 of class A ).

So, to make sure that my tests are in fact using v1 of class A, I ran them in debug mode ( using the flag `-Dmaven.surefire.debug`), attached a debugger, and evaluated the expression `A.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` and it showed me that in fact the class is being read from D1.

What's even more interesting is that if I switch the order of dependencies in my pom and put D1 under D2 and D3, my tests pass but my build fails, for the same reason of not being able to resolve a certain method.

What could be happening here? and why is IntelliJ able to run my tests successfully?

Comment: what error do you get in the terminal with the results?

Comment: @Stultuske I get the typical `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.3:test (default-test) on project myFirstProject: There are test failures.` In my surefire reports it says `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` on one of the methods in v2 of A.

Comment: ... NoSuchMethodError, seems pretty clear what that wants to say, doesn't it? maybe you have a dependency in a specific scope and you need that class in another scope. Or, in your case, you need to call a method from version X while your test is calling that from version Y